# ftpClient retreivefilestream always freezes(even for small files)

Tags: java, android, apache, connection, ftp-client

I am dealing with FTP client class in my android app. In my async task:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect("domain.com", 21);

        Log.i("result:", ftpClient.getReplyString());
        ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.USER, "login");
        Log.i("result:", ftpClient.getReplyString());
        ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.PASS, "pass");
        Log.i("result:", ftpClient.getReplyString());
        ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCmd.CWD, "/domains/domain.com/sample/path");
        Log.i("result:", ftpClient.getReplyString());

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
        InputStream is = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("file.txt");

        Log.i("hello", "there");

        (...)

    } 
}
```

After the line `InputStream is = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("file.txt")`, the rest of the code is ignored, task freezes there. The file I'm trying to read is less than 1kb. So log "hello there" is never executed.

However, previous logs with "result:" are returning positive responds: `ftp client connects to the server properly`.

Comment: Do not use that `sendCommand()` feature. Login at the normal way. There are many examples to be found: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.nl/2014/02/android-ftp-client-tutorial-with.html